# Reveal URL on mint Solana Anchor Lang

Tags: anchor, rust, nft, anchor-lang, candy-machine-v2

I want to hide the minting URL and reveal it later once a user has minted NFTs.

```
let path = "http://abc.com";
 let new_uri = format!("http://abc.com/1.json");

            invoke(
                &create_metadata_accounts_v2(
                    ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
                    ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
                    ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
                    ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                    ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                    ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                    num_title,
                    symbol,
                    new_uri,
                    Some(creator),
                    1,
                    true,
                    false,
                    None,
                    None,
                ),
                account_info.as_slice(),
            )?;
```

Answer (score 0):

that's possible. you can change metadata info.
you've used anchor, metaplex to mint nft but in my case I've used candy machine v2.
candy machine v2 supports create & update nft.
plz reference this.

https://github.com/metaplex/metaplex

I hope this will helps you.